# Displayed map from QGIS GEE Plugin not encompassing all of my roi

Tags: pyqgis, google-earth-engine, qgis-plugins, sentinel-2, google-earth-engine-python-api

I want the least cloudy Sen-2 image from a certain period of time to be the background map for my QGIS project. I have also clipped the image to a rectangle that represents my roi, ca. 50km long diagonally.

As seen in the picture below, the resulting display was clipped, but does not encompass all of my area. Why is that, and how can I display a map for all of my roi?

[image]

Code used in the QGIS Python editor with an active, functioning GEE plugin:

```
import ee
from ee_plugin import Map

# Define the region of interest
roi = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([12.25810878,48.60268418,12.75461025,48.78060328])

# Define the date range of interest
start_date = '2023-03-01'
end_date = '2023-05-01'

# Load the Sentinel-2 image collection, filter it, sort by cloud cover
collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR') \
  .filterDate(start_date, end_date) \
  .filterBounds(roi) \
  .sort('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE')

# Retrieve the image with the least cloud cover from the collection
least_cloudy_image = ee.Image(collection.first()).clip(roi)

#Define the visualization parameters
vizParams = {
  'bands': ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
  'min': 0,
  'max': 3000,
#  'gamma': [0.95, 1.1, 1]
};

#Center the map and display the image
Map.setCenter(12.54587698, 48.66964481, 10);
Map.addLayer(least_cloudy_image, vizParams, 'colour composite');
```

Answer (score 0):

The image that you are adding doesn't have a large enough footprint to cover your ROI. You can see this here:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/be067dcddfd6a9009adf3773de84b537

```js
var roi = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([12.25810878,48.60268418,12.75461025,48.78060328])

var start_date = '2023-03-01'
var end_date = '2023-05-01'

var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR') 
  .filterDate(start_date, end_date) 
  .filterBounds(roi) 
  .sort('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE')

var least_cloudy_image = ee.Image(collection.first())//.clip(roi)
var vizParams = {
  'bands': ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
  'min': 0,
  'max': 3000,
  'gamma': [0.95, 1.1, 1]
};
Map.centerObject(roi)
Map.addLayer(roi, {}, "ROI")
Map.addLayer(least_cloudy_image, vizParams, "Single S2 image")
Map.addLayer(least_cloudy_image.clip(roi), vizParams, "Single S2 image clipped to ROI")
```

You used `.sort("CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE")` and then used `.first()` to get `least_cloudy_image`. Consider using `.sort("CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE", False)` and then `.mosaic()` instead. This way, the images are sorted from high cloudy percentage to low cloudy percentage. Mosaic will put [the last image on top where there is overlap](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/ic_composite_mosaic), so you will get the least cloudy pixel percentage and cover more area of your ROI.

However, note that for your ROI and date range, the observations for the eastern part of your ROI are all cloudy. I added a filter for `CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTANGE` and played with different values. It seems that the lowest cloudy pixel percentage for the eastern side of your roi for this date range is about 44%:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/a8172615deb67139cbc7ecbe33de927a

```js
var roi = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([12.25810878,48.60268418,12.75461025,48.78060328])

var start_date = '2023-03-01'
var end_date = '2023-05-01'

var collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR') 
  .filterDate(start_date, end_date) 
  .filterBounds(roi) 
  .filter(ee.Filter.lt("CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE",44))
  .sort('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', false) // Last goes on top, so we want sort from HIGH to LOW cloudy pixel percentage

print(collection)
print(collection.aggregate_array("CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE"))

var least_cloudy_image = collection.mosaic()
var vizParams = {
  'bands': ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
  'min': 0,
  'max': 3000,
  //'gamma': [0.95, 1.1, 1]
};
Map.centerObject(roi)
Map.addLayer(roi, {}, "ROI")
Map.addLayer(least_cloudy_image.clip(roi), vizParams, "Mosaic clipped to ROI")
```